# Wildcard item throwing error on language switching

Tags: multilingual, wildcards

I have implemented a wildcard item in my project to handle two dynamic ids.
The url is like:

`http://test82.local/min/landing/abxc1534/7364fbg`.

It works fine on first load.
But if I switch language using our (custom) language switcher, the url becomes this:

`http://test82.local/min/landing/,-w-,/,-w-,`

And it shows item not found.
Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: It this language switcher from SXA or is it your custom language switcher? What is its code?

Comment: No, Its a custom language switcher. Will post code in sometime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we see the code we'll be sure, but I'm rather convinced the problem is that your custom language switcher is asking the url from the page in the other languages through the Sitecore API - which is a normal procedure. But if Sitecore is not aware of any logic to create the url you want for the wildcard, Sitecore will generate it with the `,-w-,` sections you are seeing.

To fix this, you need to make sure that your code knows how to generate the correct urls. You might consider a custom link provider...